# I overwrite /bin/sh how do I restore it?

Tags: shell

I am new to Linux and thought `/bin/sh` was a folder.

I did **`mv path/to/file /bin/sh`** and now I can't open terminal and Ubuntu Software anymore. There are probably more broken programs I haven't noticed yet.

I get the error:

> Failed to spawn child process `/bin/sh` Too many layers of symbolic links

Any advice?

I am running Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: You must have been doing that as root (the system administrator account). It's easy to break any system if you run as administrator. Particularly since you're new I would strongly recommend that you don't routine login as root but set yourself up a normal user account

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/bin/sh` is a symlink, and overwriting didn't actually delete anything, it just invalidates the link.

Which is a problem because all kinds of scripts use `/bin/sh` in the shebang header. This is probably why various random things are also failing.

You need to, as root or via sudo:<sup>1</sup>

```
cd /bin 
rm sh 
ln -s dash sh
```

Hopefully the meaning of that is clear enough, since depending on what mechanism
you find to do this using absolute paths may be easier (the original link likely did not use an absolute path but this should not matter much).  If you are unfamiliar with [(symbolic) file links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) see `man ln`.

This should allow you to use a terminal normally again. If it works, you probably want to reboot in case any failed script from earlier has ongoing consequences.

1. This is Debian/Ubuntu and family specific; other distros may not include the `dash` shell and instead symlink to `bash`.  If there's no `dash` in `/bin`, use `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

A (generic) solution to this kind of problems is to find out what package the destroyed file belongs to, and reinstall that one. How to do that depends on your distribution's package manager. On RPM based ones it would go:

```
rpm -qf /bin/sh         # Package is bash-5.1.0-2.fc34.x86_64 here
yum -y reinstall bash
```